# Are the Notifications on Firebase using a cloud?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

A simple question to those "in the know", so probably only Frank Van Puffelen :P Are the notifications sent by the notifications console
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDEG9.png)

going thorugh a cloud of any sort? I would assume they are treated the same way as Firebase Cloud Messaging, so they go through a cloud. But is it right?

Answer (score 4):

Firebase Notifications is built on top of Firebase Cloud Messaging and uses all the same underlying infrastructure to deliver the notification messages as FCM does.